Why does Cassandra need consensus when we can use read-repairs?
As per DDIA (Design data intensive application) to make writes atomic in distributed databases we can use read repair which means lets say if client made read request to 3/5 replica nodes and on two of the them it found staled data it will make sure the latest or fresh data is available on majority of replicas before completing the client request.
This seems to made the write atomic across distributed database and ensuring lineariazability.
Then why we need paxos in cassandra ? what were the problems the above mechanism failed to resolve ?

The scenario you describe does not cover 'Compare and Set' operations which inherently would be a race condition.

Cassandra uses the Paxos protocol for reaching consensus with linearizable consistency among distributed replicas for lightweight transactions (compare-and-set operations for conditional statements, e.g. CREATE ... IF EXISTS, INSERT ... IF NOT EXISTS).
To be clear Cassandra uses Paxos to achieve linearizability, not for achieving consistency or atomicity.
Read-repair is the mechanism by which replicas which are determined to have out-of-date data during a read request (for whatever reason) are synchronised with other replicas to make them consistent.
Unlike traditional relational database which store data in normalised tables, Cassandra's data model is optimised for application queries such that data is duplicated (denormalised) in multiple tables. When data is written, there is a separate statement for each table which are batched together so they are executed as a single atomic operation. Cassandra achieves atomicity by first persisting the batch to a log on 2 nodes before issuing each statement in the batch so that if any one those statements fail, the mutation can be replayed from the batch log to make all the replicas consistent eventually.
I think you're confusing these three different concepts which are distinct in their own right so hopefully this clarifies it for you. Cheers!
